# Use ffmpeg to cut out the first chapter

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to remove the first chapter of a TV show rip. The idea is to have something similar to netflix, where the first episode will show the intro then the consecutive episodes don't.

I've been getting the chapter time with ffprobe then doing it manually with this

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -ss <CHAPTERTIME> -i "%%A" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "tmp.mp4" && DEL "%%A" && RENAME "tmp.mp4" "%%A"
```

How do I pass the first chapter time code value so ffmepg knows where to seek to?

Also hoping to use the same the same value to offset the subtitles so they align after the cut.

Note: The machine I've doing the cutting on is windows but I can use my FreeBSD server if that's easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the worst way to do it, but atleast it works, still cant get it to work in batch.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffprobe -show_chapters -print_format flat "%%A" > out.txt

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"chapters.chapter.1.start_time=" out.txt') do (
set S=%%a
set S=!S:~30,20!
echo !S!
)

for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -ss !S! -i "%%A" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "tmp.mp4" && DEL "%%A" && RENAME "tmp.mp4" "%%A"

endlocal
```